# Spring security changing sessionid

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.1.4 and I have the following problem:
I implemented my custom `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and I implemented a cache `SessionRegistry`. 
The problem is that the session id that I get in the `SessionRegistry.registerNewSession` is different then the on i get in `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler .onAuthenticationSuccess`

The session registery is called first.
what is the correct one? How can I get the same in both?

Is there a way that the custom SessionRegistry.registerNewSession will take the spring security session id?

Answer (score 3):

Just a mere guess. But it sounds like the following issue.

In Spring security by default there is a feature enabled called session fixation protection.
It migrates the session to a new ID for a security reason.
Imagine somebody supplies you an url with an existing session ID via email, you click the link and login.
Now the person who can supplied you the url, can simply hack your account by using the supplied session id.

If you want to disable it, you can do so by putting the following line in your spring security configuration. However be aware of the risk.

```
<http .. >
...
<session-management session-fixation-protection="none">
...
</http>
```

Comment: Is there a way that the custom SessionRegistry.registerNewSession will take the spring security session id?

Comment: Except for what I explained above not. But what are you trying to achieve? The job of the session registry is to persist a session and of the successhandler to perform some action after a login. Why would you need the same session ID for that?

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved it was with the below steps:

1. Added a new bean for `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy`

   ```xml
   <bean id="sessionFixationProtectionStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy" />
   ```
2. Added the new bean in # 1 as a property to the `AuthenticationFilter` bean

   ```xml
   <bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
       ...
       <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />
       ...
   </bean>
   ```
3. Added a session management configuration with `session-fixation-protection` property in the `<security:http>` tag

   ```xml
   <security:http>
       <security:headers />
       <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
       ...
       <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="changeSessionId" />
   </security:http>
   ```

Per Spring Security doco, `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` is used as `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` for Java EE Servlet API implementations pre 3.1 - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.html, whilst from Servlet API 3.1, `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy` should be used.